# Android how to turn on flash light when scanning bar code through zxing library?

Tags: android

I am unable to find a solution in my application that is how to turn on flash light when i scan a bar code with zxing library intent integrator class. the scan bar code is following.

```
    public void scanNow() {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);//ONE_D_COD E_TYPES
    integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
    Camera cam = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
    p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    cam.setParameters(p);
    cam.startPreview();
    integrator.setScanningRectangle(10, 10);
    integrator.setResultDisplayDuration(0);
    integrator.setWide(); // Wide scanning rectangle, may work better for 1D barcodes
    integrator.setCameraId(0);
    ;        // Use a specific camera of the device
    integrator.initiateScan();
    }
```

Please give me solution so that i can implement this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called **setTorch(Camera.Parameters parameters, boolean on)** which you can find here [CameraConfigurationUtils.java](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/6d61977c2efd578f67830305791e5a0a06c263e2/android-core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationUtils.java)

I haven't tested it yet. Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the Zxing Scanner (https://github.com/zxing/zxing), then in the MainActivity.cs file there is the following method for activating the flash:

Button flashButton;
            View zxingOverlay;

```
        buttonScanCustomView = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonScanCustomView);
        buttonScanCustomView.Click += async delegate {

            //Tell our scanner we want to use a custom overlay instead of the default
            scanner.UseCustomOverlay = true;

            //Inflate our custom overlay from a resource layout
            zxingOverlay = LayoutInflater.FromContext(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ZxingOverlay, null);

            //Find the button from our resource layout and wire up the click event
            flashButton = zxingOverlay.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonZxingFlash);
            flashButton.Click += (sender, e) => scanner.ToggleTorch();

            //Set our custom overlay
            scanner.CustomOverlay = zxingOverlay;

            //Start scanning!
            var result = await scanner.Scan();

            HandleScanResult(result);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use CompoundBarcodeView instance.
And then simply call setTorchOn() and setTorchOff() to to switch on or swith off the flashLight.